# Add and remove event listeners conditionally in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On right click, context menu appear in my app with button which set's a `isSelecting` state to `true`. In the same time, two event listeners are added to a `document` - one to handle mouse over and one to handle click. Both these event should be active only when `isSelecting` is true and the `onclick` event set `isSelecting` to false. Unfortunately, currently one I add event listeners in `useEffect` via setting `isSelecting` to `true` in my context menu, `onclick` event is immidiately called. How to prevent its execution until I click one more time?

```
  const handleMouseOver = (e: any) => {
    let target = e.target as HTMLElement;
    let selectableTarget: HTMLElement | null = target.hasAttribute('data-type')
      ? target
      : null;
    while (selectableTarget === null && target.parentElement) {
      target = target.parentElement;
      selectableTarget = target.hasAttribute('data-type') ? target : null;
    }

    if (selectableTarget !== prevRef.current) {
      prevRef.current?.classList.remove(...highlightClasses);
      prevRef.current = selectableTarget;
      prevRef.current?.classList.add(...highlightClasses);
    }
  };

  const handleClick = async () => {
    setIsSelecting(false);
    prevRef.current?.classList.remove(...highlightClasses);
    toast({
      title: 'Skopiowano!',
      description: 'Teraz wklej zawartość do edytora Wizards',
    });
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText(prevRef.current?.outerHTML || '');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isSelecting) {
      document.addEventListener('mouseover', handleMouseOver);
      document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
    } else {
      document.removeEventListener('mouseover', handleMouseOver);
      document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
    }

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mouseover', handleMouseOver);
      document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
    };
  }, [isSelecting]);

  return (
    <ContextMenu open={open} setOpen={setOpen} targetElement={editor.view.dom}>
      {(event) => (
        <div>
          {mathPanel && (
            <Button
              onClick={async () => {
                await navigator.clipboard.writeText(mathPanel.node.attrs.id);
                close();
              }}
              variant='ghost'
            >
              Kopiuj #ID
            </Button>
          )}
          <Button
            variant='ghost'
            onClick={() => {
              // close();
              setIsSelecting(true);
            }}
          >
            Kopiuj fragment
          </Button>
        </div>
      )}
    </ContextMenu>
  );
};
```

My desired behaviour is: set `isSelecting` to true by using context menu -> add event lsiteners to `document` -> set `isSelecting` to false on the next click -> disable event lsiteners

Comment: The refs of functions are changed when the component re-renders. So in your case, the refs of functions will be not the same with the functions that are added as an event listener. So it means you can't remove them by using removeEventListener. Could you try it again after moving the functions used by addEventListener to useEffect? Maybe its reason can be that.